# Value object to json in go

Tags: json, go

I have a struct which contains an other struct as value object.

```
type User struct {
    Name  string            `json:"name"``
    Email valueobject.Email `json:"email"`
}
```

The `valueobject.Email` looks like this:

```
type Email struct {
    value string
}
func (e *Email) Value() string {
    return e.Value
}
```

I want the value object as an immutable object, there is also a "factory" method in this is not necessary for my problem.

Now I want to return the User struct as json and therefor I use

```
response := map[string]interface{}{"user": User}
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
```

The result is:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": {
            "Email: "johndoe@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

But I want something link this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need `valueobject.Email` to implement the `json.Marshaler` interface:

```
func (e *Email) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  return json.Marshal(e.Value())
}
```

That is the bare-minimum to implement what you are asking for. By implementing the `json.Marshaler` interface, it allows you to customize how `json.Marshal` renders your value.

Another option is to simplify `Email` into just a wrapper for `string`, instead of a struct:

```
type Email string

func (e Email) Value() string {
  return e
}
```

Since strings are already handled by `json.Marshal`, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

To make your Email type marshal the way you'd like, you'll need to make it implement the [json.marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface. [GopherAcademy](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/) uses the following example:

```
func (d Dog) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
return json.Marshal(NewJSONDog(d)) }
```